# Infinite product limit and estimate

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, infinite-product

I came across this product series in research and need to understand and estimate it. It appears to be unbound, but what would be the law?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{(1 - \frac1{2k+1})}$$
Many thanks if you know the answer.

Comment: To clarify: you're multiplying over odd integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is write the product term to accurately reflect the fact that multiplication is taking place over odds:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k+1}{2k}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)$$
Regarding convergence, a useful theorem says if $a_k>0$, then $\sum a_k$ and $\prod (1+a_k)$ converge or diverge together: **not** to the same value, but one is finite if and only if the other is. So we can study
$$\frac{1}{2}
\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k},
$$a well-known series known to be divergent called the *harmonic series*. Your intuition is correct, i.e. the product is unbounded (does not converge).

Comment: Not sure what is "the law" meant in the OP, but I would add $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}$.

Comment: @metamorphy in fact, you might consider writing up something about the Wallis products, as OP may not know about them.

Comment: @metamorphy that's exactly what was meant, many thanks!

Comment: @metamorphy, if not too much asking, if there's a reference for that very useful asymptotic limit, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Serge: I would dive into [$\Gamma$ stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler's_definition_as_an_infinite_product) (more specifically [this one](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.8#E1) with $z=1/2$; I've even started to write a proof, but thought I better stop reproducing books).

Comment: But, as noted by @Integrand, this can indeed be deduced from [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).